# Set a default for the name field - Lightning experience

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience

I have a object where the key field is basically a date.  So the user selects a date and then saves, a trigger then changes the name field to [date] + ': " +  [owner] which allows for me to have a two part primary key  (owner and date validated by duplication rule).

Normally, I could visualforce this up and make it happen.  However, with the lightning experience it's not as easy.  Any ideas how I can have the name field autopopulate with a default value in lightning?

Comment: What about a quick action?

Comment: I'll suggest the quick action. Another alternative is don't use the name field. Use a custom field and rely on the before trigger to populate the name when the record is saved.

Comment: I'll take a look into quick action.  That was my next step to avoid the name and use duplicate rules on a non-key field and then just use autonumber to avoid user intervention.

Comment: This is global quick actions correct?  It's a parent object so I need to access it from a Tab.  I'm having issues trying to figure out how to access the global quick actions.  I don't know where they are after creating them.

Comment: Looks like it might not be available yet but have a feeling they will be adding it at some point... https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lex_migration_customization/lex_migration_customization_actions "Specifically, these types of global actions are supported in the menu: Log a Call and Create a Record quick actions that point to the Events, Notes, and Tasks objects."

Comment: Quick action worked.  I was able to spoof it by not putting the name field on the quick action screen.  Apparently it was okay with submitting that and my trigger ran a-okay.  I'm going to try and build a lightning component to auto fill it in.  If you want to put that as an answer I can mark it'